# Has anyone else heard rumors of a very old fiction about disintegrator pistols on other planets?

Tags: story-identification

Years ago, I read a magazine article, possibly in *Discover*, about how in the 17th or 18th century, someone (possibly a Frenchman?) was writing about interplanetary journeys of men armed with disintegrator pistols.

I've been looking around, trying to figure out if I'm mis-remembering.

I found a webpage that reads:

> Cyrano de Bergerac's Comical History of the States and Empires of the
>   Moon (1659) and Sun (1687) include marvelous inventions such as solar
>   energy converters and talking machines. ... The first known fictions
>   even vaguely set in future time are Francis Cheynell's six-page
>   political tract Aulicus: His Dream of the King's Second Coming to
>   London (1644) and Jacques Guttin's Epigone, Story of the Future
>   Century (1659).  ...Voltaire took a similar stance in Micromégas
>   (1732), notable as the first known story of visitors from other
>   planets: two giants...

http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~hbf/sfhist.html

All that looks great, but none of that mentions disintegrator pistols.

Much, much later, in 1898, *Edison's Conquest of Mars* and *War of the Worlds* featured disintegrator weapons and death rays.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Science-Fiction: The Early Years](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873384164) by Everett Bleiler is a pretty thorough encyclopedia of early science fiction, I looked through all the stories listed under the index entry "Disintegrator Rays", the earliest one was "A Century Hence or, a Romance of 1941" by George Tucker, written around 1841. The description says "The great scientific triumph of the day is a telescope with a thirty-foot mirror, which can focus a beam so tight that it can cut through steel bars (like a modern laser)."

Comment: I suppose I may have mixed up the "disintegrator" with a fantastic voyage or the pre-sci-fi era: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/fantastic_voyages lists various early stories which may have been the "interplanetary" stories that I read about, even if they did not have "disintegrators."